# Why do the twins wear masks?

Tags: trese

In the animated version of *Trese*, the titular character's bodyguards turn out to

> be the children of the war god,

which is a fair explanation of their floating and ability to manifest weapons.

The [sock and buskin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sock_and_buskin) masks that they manifest whenever they fight were given to them by Trese's father. We know that the twins are capable of regenerating their masks and that they removed them when

> they temporarily fell under the control of their father.

However, why were they given the masks in the first place? They don't seem to need them to use or control their powers, their identities hardly seem to be secret, and the intimidation factor has to be minimal in comparison with their dead black eyes, floating, and supernatural weaponry.

Comment: [It's called fashion. You wouldn't understand](https://giphy.com/embed/paWQwjlM2mKKGa2vsR/video).